# limit switches to control motor direction

Tags: switches, relay, dc-motor, polarity, reverse-polarity

I am trying to use two limit switches and two DPDT relays to control the direction of the motor.  When the power is applied the motor should rotate one direction (direction for this question isn't important).  Also, at this point (initialization) neither switch will be energized. The motor will rotate and move until it energizes the second limit switch (labeled Switch 2).  At this point, the direction of the motor should reverse.  The motor and hardware will then move towards switch one.  Once the motor reaches switch one it should stop completely (not reverse direction again). Below is my basic wiring diagram.

I wired it up and when I supply power the motor rotates.  However, whenever switch 2 is energized I can hear relay 2 energize and de-energizes quickly but no motor rotation.

Also, I am trying to implement a latching relay when the motor reverses direction.  I do not know if my problem is occurring there.

Finally, I am having problems trying to figure out how to have the motor stop once switch 1 is energized.

Any help with my two problems (reversal of direction, and stop when switch 1 energized) would be greatly appreciated.

[image: initial wiring diagram]

Comment: Do your latching relays require a pulse to change states?  What are you using for the pulses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial condition: no relays energized. One set of RY2's direct power one direction to the motor.
Second condition: SW2 triggered, its NO contact energizes RY2, which reverses motor polarity and **latches itself** (you'll need a pair of diodes or another relay contact set to accomplish both reversal and latching).
Third condition: SW2 released, RY2 is still latched, mechanism swings the opposite direction.
Fourth condition: SW1 triggered, its NO contact energizes RY1. An NC contact set on RY1 breaks RY2's latching circuit, and the same NO contact latches RY1 on until power drops away. The second RY1 contact set's NC interrupts power to the motor.

EDIT: Here's what I have in mind:
[image]

Comment: Something to consider, if there is no way for you to know if the relay is latched on t=0 (initial powerup (time=zero)) you can have unexpected action.  Elevator doors work in the fashion you are describing.  The motor rotates one way (closing the doors) unless the limit (safety) switch is hit.  At this point, it reverses the motor to open the door back up. Depending on you application, knowing what relays are latched on startup may or may-not be an issue for you.

Comment: @EnemyOftheStateMachine, I was thinking electrically-latched relays instead of mechanically latched relays. I agree - mechanically latched relays could be really problematic here.

Comment: @TD,  your comment is what I am looking for but having problems figuring out how to wire it. I am new to electronics. Can you provide a basic drawing that I can try to use to follow your steps.  Also,  the reason I am not too worried (at this moment in time) about the mechanism resting squarely on Switch one is because I plan on incorporating this design into my larger contraption.  The larger contraption sends a pulse after a specific amount of time (calculated via a ratemeter). I plan to use that pulse (extend it if I have to) to move the mechanism off switch one to start each cycle.

Comment: @user2755399 - Schematic added. It should do everything you want it to do, including automatically resetting itself at the end of each cycle.

Comment: @TD, thank you.  In the diagram it does not appear that you routed the power through the NC contact of switch one.  Am I miss-reading the schematic or the first line of your comment?

Comment: @TD, both of my relays are DPDT. Is there anyway I can combine two of the poles in relay 2 within your schematic? Or is there anyway to wire it?  I am working with standard radio shack relays that I can attach to a breadboard and then solderable breadboard once I get it working.

Comment: I've added a second schematic again - that should also work fine, and requires only DPDT relays, with a diode for latching. Nearly any rectifier (1N4001 is fine, dime a dozen at Radio Shack) will do for the diode unless you're using a lot more voltage than I think you are. I haven't actually found a use yet for the second pole on RY1.

Comment: This maybe a rookie comment but to me it appears that relay 2 will always be energized.  The wire running to the right and parallel to switch two, appears to run through the NC contact on the top pole, then through the diode, and through com and out NC for relay 1 and back to the coil of relay 2. Then it appears that the top pole of relay two flips and i'm lost.  Is that correct, will there be an automatic flip due to how the wires are listed? If so, why?

Comment: @user2755399, not a rookie comment at all. I had screwed up the diode's connection. Fixed it now...

Comment: I can see how the motor rotates as the mechanism is moving to the right and once it reaches switch 2 the polarity switches and the mechanism moves to the left.  But, once the mechanism mechanism leaves contact with switch 2, I do not see how it remains latched to keep the mechanism moving to the left.

Comment: @user2755399, That's where the diode comes in. When RY2 is energized, the lower set of contacts connects the diode to +V. The diode routes that +V through RY1's NC contacts and back to RY2's coil, so until RY2 is energized, RY1 is electrically latched "on".

Comment: @TD, so do you think it can't be done with two DPDT relays?

Comment: @user2755399, I had erred again, editing a previous schematic. I've now simplified my entire answer, leaving only today's version... which should now work as intended, using two DPDT relays, one contact set of which is now spare.

Comment: @TD, I wired and tested it out.  When switch 1 or 2 is closed the motor stops until the switch is let go. However, temporarily closing switch 2 is not reversing the direction of the motor (and keeping the direct reversed until switch 1 is closed).  Does this appear to be something on my end?

Comment: @user2755399... it sounds almost like the diode is reversed. Its anode (no band) end should connect to the RY2's common contact, its cathode (band) should connect to the RY2's coil. Reversed, it becomes a dead short circuit across the coil when SW2 is pressed.

Comment: @TD,  I have it starting to work.  I think it was either my diode couldn't handle the current (I switched to a 1N4001, yes your recommendation so I take full accountability for that mistake) or there wasn't enough current to latch or keep the relay 2 coil energized.  however, the majority of the time after switch 2 reverses the direction and I press switch 1 the motor powers down and doesn't turn back on.  Any ideas?

Comment: @TD, i don't know if it has to do with my power supply.  I am running at 7V about about 0.15A.  When I press switch 2 I see the current jump to about 0.75A.

Comment: @user2755399, That's how I understood the original intent. EDIT: I mean the shutoff when SW1 is pressed; RY1 is self-latched on, shutting off the motor entirely until the power is cycled.

Comment: @TD, Switch 1 should stop the motor when the switch is pressed, but allow rotation once the switch isn't pressed any more.  I may have not been clear about that.  The design I want to incorporate this into will be sending an external pulse to initiate the movement of the motor (off switch 1).  is there any easy way to incorporate the external pulse (in the form of a button)?

Comment: @TD, got the switch implemented to un-latch (?) relay one after one cycle.  Circuit is up and fully running.  Thank for taking the extra time to get everything worked out! (can't upvote until I get the required reputation, but will once I can)

Comment: @user2755399... very **cool**! That is exactly what I come here for, to help folks get stuff done. 8)

Answer (score 0):

The dashed lines indicate mechanical connections, and the circuit works like this:

With power ( + and - ) connected and limit switches LS1 and LS2 disengaged, the only avenue available for current flow will be from the supply positive (+) to K1-1, then through K1-2, the motor, K1-5 and 4, and finally through K2-1 and 2 to the supply negative, (-).

That will cause the motor to rotate clockwise, and after a time it will engage LS1, closing LS1-C and NC, which will connect the supply positive to K1-11 and allow current to flow through the relay coil and into the supply negative through K2-1 and 2.

When that happens, the magnetic field generated by K1's coil will cause K1-7 and 8 to close, in parallel with LS1, which will latch K1 even if LS1 is later opened.

K1's coil being energized will also cause its other two sets of contacts to switch, with the result being that the supply connections to the motor will be reversed, plugging it and then causing it to rotate anti-clockwise.

That will cause LS1 to open, but since K1-7 and 8 will keep K1's coil energized after LS1 opens, K1 will be latched and the motor will continue to run.

Some time later the motor will cause LS2 to be closed, and when it does it'll energize K2, which will cause K2-2 and 3 to close, latching K2.

When K2 and 3 are closed, however, K2-1 and 2 will open, breaking the connection between supply negative and the motor and between supply negative and K1, so the motor will stop and K1 will be de-energized until power is disconnected, LS2 returned to its open state, and power reconnected, starting the cycle anew.

[image]

Comment: That last will require manual intervention before the next "reboot" cycle, true? To get off the LS2 limit switch?

Comment: TDHofstetter: True.

Comment: @EM, thank you for the comment.  I am new to electronics and am having problems following your diagram.  I am having difficulty with some of your labels such as K1C (closed contact for relay 1?), as well as where are the NO contacts for each relay (dotted lines maybe). I am trying to follow the diagram with your comments but still have difficulty.  Can you draw the image as you would for a beginner? Thanks and once again I apologize my new lack of experience.

Comment: @user...: Done.

Comment: @EM, Thanks for the update.  I have two DPDT relays.  The diagram appears to use a TPDT.  Can it be done with only two DPDTs?

Comment: @user: Dunno...